# RubyMine 8 development not working. Keeps saying No Rails Found in SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sdk, rubymine, ruby-on-rails-5

Title kind of explains it. In both the `Development Configuration` and `Preferences` -> `Languages` -> `Ruby SDK and Gems` settings I have the correct Ruby version/Gemset selected. But it still just saying:

> Error running Development: the_factory: [No Rails found in SDK]

I've used RubyMine on tons of projects and this has never given me a problem. But this is a new project, using `Rails 5` and `Ruby v2.3.0`, and I just can't figure out what's going on here.

This is in `Ruby SDK and Gems` settings in RubyMine 8:
[image]

And this is my `Development` config:
[image]

**Update**

When I run `rails server` in my project folder, it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I checked it out a little on [RubyMine help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/quick-start-guide.html) and I found this magical phrase:

> RubyMine supports Ruby versions 1.8.6 to 2.2

[image]

So I removed my `rvm` Ruby 2.3 version, installed Ruby 2.2.4, create a `gemset` with Rails 5. Then I assigned that gemset to my project and Voilá! It worked as expected.

**Note:** This answer my specific question at the date I write this. But this obviously is not a long term answer, so if you are a future boy/girl with this very same problem, first check if your RubyMine version support `Ruby >v2.3` before remove your current Ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was that I had several Rails gem versions installed in my project directory.

```
gem uninstall rails
```

was the way to go, removing any unwanted versions. Feels like a contradiction - but uninstalling Rails meant that RubyMine could find Rails.